# How to know subscriberKey is mapped to which attribute in marketing cloud exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud

we are using SubscriberKey to send emails to the subscribers in the marketing cloud. i wanted to know on which attribute the subscriberKey is mapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All Subscribers** will show you the mapping.

You can export the data from the toolbar.  Additionally, you can use a [**Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/) of Subscribers and Attributes data.

Comment: we have SFMC 1.0 in that subscriberKey is off but we are sending mails using subscriberkey and i want to know how it is taking attribute to send the emails any suggestion from your side (is it taking emailAddress as default)

Comment: If subscriberKey is turned off, then emailaddress is used by default.